# Shadows not casted/received with HDR environment texture in Three js

Tags: node.js, three.js, 3d-model, threejs-editor

I am new to three js and I’ve been working on a project where I want to cast a shadow of the import 3D model which is download from this [link](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/mclaren-f1-1993-nfs2-edition-by-alexka-05207f338bd448b69c7b6eb65ad15025) also download the HDR file from the [link](https://app.gumroad.com/) free pack.

As per the videos avaliable on the internet and while googling my problem I have found some of the issue in my code which I have changed like `scene.environment = texture;`. I have the mesh of the model to `castShadow = true` and `receiveShadow = true` also added the to `receiveShadow = true`. But still I am not able to cast the shadow.

Library version I am using:

three - v0.162.0
node - v20.11.1
vite - v5.2.0

Here is my index.js file code:

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import "./style.css";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
import { RGBELoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/RGBELoader";
// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Sizes
const sizes = {
  width: 800,
  height: 500,
};

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();

const rgbeloader = new RGBELoader();

let car3;
rgbeloader.load(
  "./WhiteNeons_NAD.hdr",
  (texture) => {
    texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
    scene.environment = texture;
    scene.castShadow = true;

    gltfLoader.load(
      "./models/car3/scene.gltf",
      (gltf) => {
        const model = gltf.scene;
        model.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        model.traverse((node) => {
          node.castShadow = node.isMesh;
          node.receiveShadow = node.isMesh;
        });
        scene.add(model);
        car3 = model;
      },
      undefined,
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  },
  undefined,
  (err) => {
    console.error("HDR:: ", err);
  }
);

// Plane
const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
const planeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x5a5a5a });
const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMat);
plane.receiveShadow = true;
plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
scene.add(plane);

const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper();
gridHelper.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(gridHelper);
// Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  45,
  sizes.width / sizes.height,
  0.1,
  1000
);
camera.position.set(5, 2, 0);
// camera.position.z = 20;
scene.add(camera);

// Renderer
const canvas = document.querySelector(".webgl");
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });

renderer.setClearColor(0xa3a3a3);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
renderer.outputColorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
renderer.toneMappingExposure = 6;

renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.render(scene, camera);

// Controls
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});

function animate(time) {
  if (car3) {
    car3.rotation.y = -time / 1000;
  }
  controls.update();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `three.js` it is not possible to cast shadows with environment maps.

You have to use a shadow casting light like a directional, point or spot light or fake shadows somehow. One option is to use `THREE.ShadowMesh` but this would only produce a planar shadow so it's not a full replacement of classic shadow mapping.